# sp_executesql with parameters syntax error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
@id NVARCHAR(12),
@query NVARCHAR(500),
@paramDef NVARCHAR(100) = N'@id NVARCHAR(12)'
```

I have a syntax error on this line below, specifically at `@id`

```
set @query = N'select * from OPENQUERY([REMOTESERVER], ''EXEC db.dbo.dwStoredProc_sp ''@id'')'''
```

Which I then use

```
exec sp_executesql @query, @paramDef, @id
```

I expect my single quotes are incorrect.

Comment: Why your parameter @id in quote?

Comment: It's left over from when I was doing it by concatenating strings to make a query, `sp_executesql` is much better.

Comment: You string is looks like `select * from OPENQUERY([REMOTESERVER], 'EXEC db.dbo.dwStoredProc_sp '@id')'`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to pass `'@id'` as a string to the SP.

This is likely what you meant:

```
set @query = N'select * from OPENQUERY([REMOTESERVER], ''EXEC db.dbo.dwStoredProc_sp ' + @id + ''')';
```

Comment: I didn't think to pass the actual value and not the placeholder. Thanks.

Comment: And what about injection? The correct answer is @juergen d answer.

Comment: I dind't try, but if you can use the parameters within the string as in juergen d's answer, that's certainly preferable.

Answer (score 4):

Your last `)` is placed wrong and you don't need quotes around your `@id`. Try

```
set @query = 
  N'select * from OPENQUERY([REMOTESERVER], ''EXEC db.dbo.dwStoredProc_sp ' + @id + ''')'
```

Comment: With this I get the error that I need to declare `@id` scalar value

Comment: Wait, so there is no safe way to do this? I must pass the parameter's literal value in `@query`? Like CRAFTY DBA said this may allow injection attacks.

Comment: @Lee: Putting it in quotes does not prevent anything. If this is a security concern for you, then you need to escape the content before anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Obviously, it is a quote issue.**

But the forum giving you an answer does not give you the tools find a issue in the future.

This is a general debugging issue.  Next time, print out the dynamic TSQL.  Cut and past into another window.

You will find your issue quickly.  Check out the little known processing-instruction command.

Great for huge multiline statements.

```
-- Old school output to message window
PRINT @query 

-- Cool instruction ?  Code in new xml tab.
SELECT @query  as [processing-instruction(TSQL)] FOR XML PATH
```

Sample use of print.

**You should give Juergen the credit!**

[image]